# NSUserDefaults NSColor extension error

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsuserdefaults

This is my first time creating an extension and I'm extending `NSUserDefaults`. I'm just using the code that I found on Apple's developer page, but I'm getting errors in the project in my .h and .m files. I created the files for macOS as the Cocoa class type. How can I fix this? Here's the code along with the errors:

**NSUserDefaults+MyColourSupport.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSUserDefaults(MyColourSupport)

-(void)setColor:(NSColor *)aColor forKey:(NSString *)aKey;
-(NSColor*)colorForKey:(NSString *)aKey;

@end
```

[image]

**NSUserDefaults+MyColourSupport.m**

```
#import "NSUserDefaults+MyColourSupport.h"

@implementation NSUserDefaults(MyColourSupport)

-(void)setColor:(NSColor*)aColor forKey:(NSString*)aKey {
    NSData *theData = [NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:aColor];
    [self setObject:theData forKey:aKey];
}

-(NSColor*)colorForKey:(NSString*)aKey {
    NSColor *theColor = nil;
    NSData *theData = [self dataForKey:aKey];

    if (theData != nil)
        theColor = (NSColor*)[NSUnarchiver unachiveObjectWithData:theData];

    return theColor;
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: try importing cocoa

Comment: That worked...thanks :) I just imported AppKit, instead of UIKit like you had originally said.

Comment: did you import UIKit.h ?

Comment: I imported appkit since this is for the mac, not iOS.